# ERR syntax error while performing SCAN operations in Redis using Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis, key-value-store

While working with Redis using Spring Data Redis, I tried to scan hash data in my server (similar to HSCAN in CLI) -

```
Cursor<Entry<Object,Object>> scan = redisTemplate.opsForHash().scan("student", new ScanOptionsBuilder().count(0).match("*").build());
```

While running this I get the below error -

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR syntax error

Can anyone help me how to solvw this.

***There are many related discussions but none of them provide clear answer.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use count > 0, or not using count at all (default is 10).

From looking at [ScanOptions.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ScanOptions.java), if count is used, it is passed to the command without any checks.

A quick check on redis-cli shows `COUNT 0` throws `ERR syntax error`.

```
> hset hash1 f v
(integer) 1
> hscan hash1 0 MATCH * COUNT 0
(error) ERR syntax error
> hscan hash1 0 MATCH * COUNT 1
1) "0"
2) 1) "f"
   2) "v"
```

See [SCAN > The COUNT option](https://redis.io/commands/scan#the-count-option) for more details. It doesn't state it has to be greater than 0 though but makes sense it should.

Comment: When I use **count > 0** or remove count parameter, the returned value by SCAN is - **org.springframework.data.redis.core.ConvertingCursor@555ec143** I want the data to be printed similar to how it is printed on CLI. @LeoMurillo

Comment: You need to call multiple times, while you capture the keys. See examples at https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.data.redis.core.ScanOptions